# How do I do a global text search in Eclipse for OS X?

Tags: macos, eclipse

What is the keyboard shortcut for a global search in Eclipse for OS X?

Essentially the equivalent of Cmd-Shift-F in Sublime Text.

Comment: Are you talking about looking for a specific string or word?

Comment: Yeah, just searching within all the files in the project.

Comment: I believe the answer is what you want. If not, let me know. There are so many ways to search things in Eclipse....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search the entire workspace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> should allow you to search the entire workspace for a string

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other option - install [STS (Spring Tool Suite)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-aka-spring-ide-and-spring-tool-suite) which supports incremental search.

Invoke by <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and enjoy:

[image]